# Does this linq-to-sql query retrieve all records and then pick one, or retrieve just one?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm looking for the highest key in a table with a quite a lot of records, and I'm wondering if LINQ to SQL does this efficiently, or if I need to take another approach to make sure the code isn't pulling across all of the records from the database.

```
        int tkey =
            (from r in GMSCore.db.Receipts
             orderby r.TransactionKey descending
             select r.TransactionKey).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is this interpreted like:

```
select Top(1) TransactionKey 
from Receipt
order by TransactionKey desc
```

Or does it pull all of the records and then filter in the C# code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It retrieves just one record. Generated query will look like:

```
SELECT TOP(1) [t0].[TransactionKey] 
FROM Receipt [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[TransactionKey] DESC
```

Query is not executed until you call `FirstOrDefault()` or other operator which forces execution (see [Classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882641.aspx)).

You even can save query definition into variable (feel the difference - not result of query execution, but query itself)

```
var query = from r in GMSCore.db.Receipts
            orderby r.TransactionKey descending
            select r.TransactionKey;

// Nothing is executed yet
int tkey = query.FirstOrDefault(); // SQL query is generated and executed
```

You can execute original query later

```
foreach(var key in query) // another SQL is generated and executed
    // ...
```

But in this case generated SQL query will look like

```
SELECT [t0].[TransactionKey] 
FROM Receipt [t0]
ORDER BY [t0].[TransactionKey] DESC
```

So, you can modify query definition until it is executed. E.g. you can add filtering, or change ordering. In fact operator which executes query also usually affects query generation - e.g. selecting first, single or max item.